# Using apostrophes in a MySQL query Java

Tags: java, mysql

so I have run into a bit of an Issue with MySQL. I have a service that allows administrators to ban users, and give a reason for their banning. This service is written fully in java... while I could use a PhP server and use the MySQL functionality in that to solve this... I feel I want to keep all of my MySQL functionality in one enviroment.

The issue comes about with the ability to give a reason, often an admin will give a reason something along the lines of "You're banned for: Griefing Bob's castle" (or something of the sort). As noticed, the ' ' cause problems, because those are used to represent Strings in MySQL.

Are there any solutions in a Java environment?

Comment: If apostrophes are breaking your query, then your system is critically unsafe and vulnerable to SQL injection. You need to start looking into parameterized queries **immediately**.

Comment: @ChrisHayes is correct and his advice cannot be emphasized enough.  There are libraries available which will handle sanitizing input for you, please avail yourself of them.

Comment: Would you mind giving me some examples of these libraries,andSQL injection, I read the wiki on it... still confused what exactly it is

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution might be Commons Lang [StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql%28java.lang.String%29). Another solution is to use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and to bind the parameters (some prefer this second option because it *usually* scales better and has faster performance).

```
// From the JavaDoc on PreparedStatement
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES "
                                 + "SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
pstmt.setInt(2, 110592)
```